# Ajax request windows phone 8 doesn't work when putting on the market

Tags: windows-phone-8, phonegap-build, mobile-application, ajax-request

I am creating a windows phone app using phonegap build .I am making ajax request to get the data from the RESTful web service .

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'someURL' +
                    '?param1=param1val' +  
                    '&param2=param2val',

            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback', // specify the callback name if you're hard-coding it
            success: successcallback,
            error: errorcallback
        });
```

When I'm deploying on registered windows 8 phone using xap deployment tool, everything work find.But when I put on the windows phone market for beta the request doesn't work.Phonegap build version I am using is 3.4.0.

Request is working fine on IOS and android devices both .

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution to this problem